# How do I apply CSS3 filter grayscale to all properties except figcaption's tag?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

How do I apply CSS3 webkit-filter grayscale to all article tags except the `<figcaption>` tag? Look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvp7nzw3/16/) for an example.

```css
.black-white {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out !important;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out !important;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out !important;
}
.black-white:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<article class="black-white">
  <figure class="featured-image">
    <a href="#">
      <figcaption>
        <img src="http://www.digital-lab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo-pietro-castro.png" alt="Logo Pietro Castro" class="project-logo" />
      </figcaption>
      <img src="http://www.digital-lab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/pietro-castro.jpg" alt="Pietro Castro" width="900" height="900" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</article>
```

Comment: Using `all` is not recommended. It gives the browswer unnecessary work to do. You should only only transition the properties actually required.

Comment: For all intent tag article, not the whole body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've nested the figcaption inside the black-white container which has the grayfilter on it. So this block (including the children) will always be grayscaled. Better would be adding the black-white class only to the elements which needs to be grayscaled. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so it works https://jsfiddle.net/kvp7nzw3/20/, but if i go over the figcaption's tag this not hover.

Answer (score 0):

A walk-around is to set the transition for all and specify a very fast one for figcaption:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms;
```

```css
.featured-image figcaption {
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.project-logo {
  display: table-cell !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 220px !important;
}
.portfolio-grid.three-columns article:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.portfolio-wrap .three-columns article {
  width: 33.3%;
}
.black-white {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms !important;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms !important;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out, figcaption img 1ms !important;
}
.black-white:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<article class="black-white">
  <figure class="featured-image">
    <a href="#">
      <figcaption>
        <img src="http://www.digital-lab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo-pietro-castro.png" alt="Logo Pietro Castro" class="project-logo" />
      </figcaption>
      <img src="http://www.digital-lab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/pietro-castro.jpg" alt="Pietro Castro" width="900" height="900" />
    </a>
  </figure>
</article>
```

Are you sure you are not confusing **transition** and **filter** ?

Comment: @Filippo It works : you asked in your title "how to apply CSS **transition** to all except figcaption", not "how to apply CSS **filter** to all except figcaption". Please use the correct words when asking a question.